# Arithmetic in batch file loop

Tags: batch-file, math, for-loop, dos

I am writing a for loop in a batch file, which is to do arithmetic to a variable each iteration. The loop looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET d=10
echo !d!

for /L %%t IN (0,1,9) DO (
    SET /A d = %d% + 10
    echo !d!
)
```

The arithmetic only is good for the first iteration. 'd' is to start at 10 and add by ten each time (10 20 30 ...) but it always stops at 20. In the output of the command prompt it will show:

```
10
20
20
...
20
20
```

How can I write this so it will add by ten for the entire loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you missed using delayed expansion in one spot.

Change `SET /A d = %d% + 10` to `SET /A d = !d! + 10`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET d=10
echo !d!

for /L %%t IN (0,1,9) DO (
    SET /A d = !d! + 10
    echo !d!
)
```

Comment: Or `set /A "d+=10"` or `set /A d = d +10`

Answer (score 1):

Do as @JosefZ says if you need the academic exercise of arithmetic in a loop. If you want to get the same result with less code you can do this.

```
for /L %%t IN (20,10,110) DO echo %%t
```

Comment: Thanks! I can get away with doing a loop but as you said, i need it done this way for the academic exercise. Also, the variable 'd' is used in a nested loop else where and has to continue on from where it left off